# Visual Studio Code doesn't add CSS Stylesheets and JS-Files to HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

I migrated my project from Visual Studio Enterprise to Visual Studio Code and now my CSS and JS-Files are not being embedded in the HTML-File anymore.
There are no error-messages. I think the problem is, that VS sees the links as webpages on my website and searches for them and doesn't find them. I come to this conclusion because of the messages in the debug console.

My code looks like this:

```
@model LoginModel;
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
 }
<head>
    <link   rel="stylesheet" href="../wwwroot/css/Home.css"
      type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../wwwroot/css/overview.css"
       type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
      **more HTML code here **
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="${workspaceFolder}/NXM_Web_Client/wwwroot/js/login.js"></script>
```

The Debug console states that:

> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
> Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/wwwroot/css/Home.css
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
> Request finished in 21.0984ms 404
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
> Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/${workspaceFolder}/NXM_Web_Client/wwwroot/js/login.js
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
> Request finished in 0.2092ms 404

The same message comes for all CSS and JS files. I allready tried marking the files as static, this didn't work.

Comment: `href="../wwwroot/css/Home.css"` should probably just be `href="/css/Home.css"`

Comment: Also, `href="${workspaceFolder}/NXM_Web_Client/wwwroot/js/login.js"` should be `href="/js/login.js"`. If these don't work, then you have other issues.

Comment: Unfortunately these two options don't work. I'm really confused.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your files are in same folder where you have saved your main html file.Just tell me after trying did it worked.

Answer (score 0):

While `../` in a URL means "Go to the parent segment of the path",  you can't go above the server root.

`wwwroot` is the root.

You are trying to go from `/` to a level above `/` (which is impossible) and then back into `/` which leaves you in `/wwwroot`.

Don't do that.

Either use a relative path which doesn't go past the root (`css/Home.css`) or use an absolute path which starts at the root (`/css/Home.css`).